# Need to get the multiple form elements in uncontrolled components in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to get the multiple form fields input values and sending that to server. But i am only able to get the last field's value on submit.
I am using uncontrolled component because i am trying to editing the form and then updating it.Please help me out to get all the form details entered in the form.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    class Update extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          info:''

         };

         this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
         }

         handleSubmit(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
     console.log(event);
             alert(event);


         }

         componentDidMount(){
           let self = this;
           axios.get('http://localhost:8080/studentById')
           .then(function(data) {
           //console.log(data);
           self.setState({info:data.data});
           });

         }

         render() {
           return (
    <div>

             <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  >

               <label className="w3-label w3-text-blue w3-large w3-margin-0 ">
                 First Name:
                 <input autoFocus type="text" className="w3-input w3-border"   defaultValue={this.state.info.Firstname} ref={(input) => this.input = input} required />
               </label>
                <label className="w3-label w3-text-blue w3-large">
                Last Name:
                 <input type="text" className="w3-input w3-border" defaultValue={this.state.info.Lastname} ref={(input) => this.input = input} required />
               </label>
                 <input className="w3-btn-block w3-blue w3-margin-bottom w3-large" type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </div>
 )};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different property names for each input inside refs callbacks (currently you override `this.input` so it points to the last input):

```
<input autoFocus type="text" className="w3-input w3-border"   defaultValue={this.state.info.Firstname} ref={(input) => this.input1 = input} required />


<input autoFocus type="text" className="w3-input w3-border"   defaultValue={this.state.info.Firstname} ref={(input) => this.input2 = input} required />
```

Then inside your component methods you can access value of an input this way:

```
 let inputValue = this.input1.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you assign all refs to the same variable. (your code simplified for showing what I mean)

```
First Name:
<input ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
Last Name:
<input ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
```

Instead use different variable for different input fields:

```
First Name:
<input ref={(input) => this.firstNameInput = input} />
Last Name:
<input ref={(input) => this.lastNameInput = input} />
```